# Screen Orientation Problem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I have build a 2.1 android application. I have used TableLayout in one activity. This Activity contains all TextViews. Infact whole Activity is filled with TextViews.

I installed this application in my mobile. It clipss the portion of activity when screen orientation changes to Landscape mode..

I have used this also : android:configChanges="orientation" ..But its not working

Comment: And now what do you want?Disable orientation change?

Comment: I dont wont to disable the screen orientation change. I dont know exactly but can't we do something like if screen orientation changes to landscape mode, add vertical scrollbar to that activity and if orientation changes to portrait mode, just display the contents. ?

Comment: Ok. It sounded like you wanted to do this. Can you post your layout xml, that way we can debug if your layout is missing something.

Comment: I solved the problem.. I just created a folder called layout-land inside res folder. And created a new (modified) xml (for landscape mode) file having the same name. It works properly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.. I just created a folder called layout-land inside res folder. And created a new (modified) xml (for landscape mode) file having the same name. It works properly..

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your layout in a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). Scrolling will appear automatically if the height of the Table is higher than the height of the screen.

Comment: I solved the problem..
I just created a folder called layout-land inside res folder. And created a new (modified) xml (for landscape mode) file having the same name. It works properly...